# How to get the promise value of a $resource result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource

I'm trying to treat the result of a REST service but I get a promise in the result data instead of the value.
I try whith this 2 approaches but I always get a promise.
For information, in the http response I get the correct value.

```
var createClientResource = $resource(
    '/createClient/:client',
    {},
    {post : {method: 'POST'}}
);

...

// first approach
return createClientResource.save(client,
    function(data) {
        client.id = data;
    }, function(error) {
        Popup.openErrorPopup('labels.errors.create.client', error);
    }
);

// second approach
return createClientResource.save(client).$promise.then(
    function(data) {
        client.id = data;
    }, function(error) {
        Popup.openErrorPopup('labels.errors.create.client', error);
    }
);
```

So, how can I correctly set the value of my client id ?

Thanks,

Regards

Comment: Yes, you always get a promise, and set the client id in the future. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I'm guessing `client.id = data.id`?

Comment: The problem is that client.id is never set with the value returned by the REST service, even in the future. The value of client.id = d {$promise: d, $resolved: true} instead of an integer. What I want is that the callback function contains the result value and not the promise.

Comment: data.id is undefined. The result is an integer and is not defined by a variable name. The HTML response is only an integer.

Comment: Can't you change you response (back-end side)?

Comment: Ok thanks, I return now a json result from back-end and it's working well with client.id = data.id.